# Sklearn train_test_split creates 1d array

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

Following scikit-learn documentation closely I am attempting to fit a dummy classif9er. However, on running a Value Error is raised. This is unexpected as previously I was using the same data: X= vector_data (a sparse matrix), and y = vector_target (a list of int) fitting with grid search cv with no such error.

Thus it must be the introduction of train_test_split.

Why does this occur in my code, as opposed to the documentation and what preventative steps should be taken please?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(vector_data, vector_target, random_state=0)
clf = DummyClassifier(strategy='stratified',random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_test,y_test)

 DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19.
Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
      DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: What are `vector_data.shape`, `X_train.shape` and `X_test.shape`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, always, always, read the warning/error message.

So, try something like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(vector_data.reshape(-1, 1), 
             vector_target, random_state=0)
```

I can't say more, just try to understand this code.